# What is the right way to implement a "Selenium driver pool" in Java?

Tags: java, multithreading, selenium, webautomation

I wrote a web automation tool using Selenium WebDriver and the geckodriver in Java.
Currently every time I execute the task, a new FirefoxDriver object is instantiated.

Now I want to implement multithreading. The first approach that came to my mind was building something like a fixed size pool - instantiate X FirefoxDriver objects at launch, wrap them in an object with a "inUse" flag and use a singleton to manage these instances.

But is this the proper solution? This is my first Selenium project and the whole concept is new to me.
I wasn't able to find an answer to that question myself after several days of googling and reading the documentation now. I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: Have you considered using something like TestNG and letting it manage the pool? With settings, you can limit the number of threads, etc. that are allowed.

Comment: I have not considered this yet, thank you for the hint! I will look into this for future web automation tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be entirely reasonable to create a pool like this. Rather than writing your own pool, i would suggest using an existing generic pool, such as the classic [Commons Pool](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-pool/) or the more modern [spf4j](http://zolyfarkas.github.io/spf4j/#a6._High_Performance_Object_Pool) pool.

For a pool to work, your code must reliably return the driver to the pool after use, or else you will leak drivers (and therefore entire browser instances!).

Therefore, i would consider a different approach: dedicating a driver to each thread. You can do this using a [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html):

```
private ThreadLocal<WebDriver> drivers = new ThreadLocal<WebDriver>() {
    @Override
    protected WebDriver initialValue() {
        return new FirefoxDriver(); // or whatever
    }

    @Override
    public void remove() {
        WebDriver driver = get();
        if (driver != null) driver.close();
        super.remove();
    }

    @Override
    public void set(WebDriver value) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
};
```

It is still possible to leak drivers, but only if threads die without removing their value from the ThreadLocal. If you have a fixed pool of threads which you reuse, you'll be fine.

A disadvantage of this approach is that you end up with a driver for every thread which has ever used a driver, even if not every one of those threads is making use of a driver at the same time. If you have a pool of threads dedicated to using drivers, and doing little else, then this will not be a significant problem. But if you have a pool of threads which do many different kinds of work, it may be.

Comment: But this way the created browser windows wouldn't get recycled, I think reusing once created windows would save much time.

Comment: Would there be an advantage in using the ThreadLocal approach instead of using Executors.newFixedThreadPool(n) and spawn a WebDriver inside the submitted thread?

Comment: @saxum As long as each thread is running multiple tests, then drivers, and browsers, will get reused. You would indeed need to combine this with an executor to make that happen.

Comment: Gotcha, now I understand. That's a elegant solution, thank you very much!